# Firebase Storage – Can't delete with size requirement

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I would like to allow users to only upload documents to their own bucket in storage with a maximum file size of 1MB, and still let them delete the files.  I have added the following, which:

```
match /myusers/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId && request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024;
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

I am testing both in the simulator and live in my project.  This doesn't let me delete the document (`access denied`).  If I remove `&& request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024;` from the rule above, the the document can be deleted (but then won't prevent upload of files greater than 1MB.

I thought maybe it was rejecting it because `request.resource` is `null`, so I tried the following:

```
match /myusers/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId && (request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024 || request.resource == null);
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

Still, deleting fails with the following error (in the simulator):

> Error: simulator.rules line [5], column [16]. Property resource is undefined on object.

[image]

I have looked at all of these solutions and modified the rule as many ways as I can think of, to no avail:

- [Firebase Storage Allow Deleting Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534295/firebase-storage-allow-deleting-files)
- [Firestore Rules Simulator - Resource undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874357/firestore-rules-simulator-resource-undefined)
- [Firebase Storage Post rules apply to Delete rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922124/firebase-storage-post-rules-apply-to-delete-rules)
- [Firebase Cloud Storage security rule for deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919867/firebase-cloud-storage-security-rule-for-deleting)

**Does anyone know how to set a max size for the file allowed but still allow for deleting?**

Comment: Hmm... that last one should work, except that I'm not sure what happens if you dereference `null`. Can you try with only `request.resource == null`? If that works correctly, try swapping the conditions in the or: `(request.resource == null || request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024)`.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, our thikning is very much in line here -- tried both of these as well.  It also fails with `allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId && request.resource == null`.   And, in my screenshot, I did actually swap the order to `(request.resource == null || request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024)` in case it was actually crashing on `request.resource.size` due to attempting to access `size` from a `null` object (`request.resource`).  Both didn't work, but the solution I just posted below does! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out!  Here's what works both in production **and** in the simulator :)

```
match /myusers/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId && 
                  (request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024 || request.method == 'delete');
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

p.s. @Doug Stevenson, if you're able to submit a note internally, I imagine that it would be very helpful for others if `request.method` examples with `delete`, `update`, `get`, and/or `create` could be added to the documentation!

**EDIT:**

Also, this works in both the simulator and production (and is a bit more readable than the first option, in my opinion).  Thanks to @Doug Stevenson on the tip!

```
match /myusers/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId && request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024;
  allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId 
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about the `request.method` property.

Comment: Actually what's needed is broken-out rules for each granular type of operation, just like Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, adding that to the documentation would be great too! I tested that in the simulator & production and it works as well!  I've updated my answer to include both options :)

Comment: Huh, I didn't think cloud storage had a delete rule, since it's not documented. It only shows read and write.

Comment: I honestly didn't know either, but figured it was worth a try when I took a look through the firestore rules you mentioned haha

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, this is just a bug in the console simulator.  I wrote actual (Android) app code against these rules, and I was able to create and delete the content with no problems.  The problem is that the simulator doesn't understand how to interpret `request.resource == null`, and just fails the whole thing as a result.

I'll file a bug report internally for this, but you should always check against your rules against the actual product if something doesn't make sense, as it's difficult to keep the simulator fully in sync.

Comment: Hi Doug, an "Access Denied" error is also returned on my web app when I try to delete

Comment: This bug is still present 2 years later.