# Firestore Security Rule denying read/write on firebase-storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Trying to add security rules to storage. When I add a security rule to make sure only authenticated users should be allowed with read/write, simulator is working. But when I try to add another constraint on the size of a file, I'm encountering an error.

The following is the Security Rule:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    }
  }
}
```

I have files under `files\` 
I get the following error in simulator:

```
Simulated read denied
```

Error details:

```
Error: simulator.rules line [4], column [29]. Property resource is undefined on object.
```

Issue happens if I try to simulate write as well.

EDIT1: **IMPORTANT**

OK! I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228842/firebase-storage-cant-delete-with-size-requirement?noredirect=1&lq=1) question and tried experimenting a bit on that line and got the simulator allowing read/write! I made the following change:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null && (request != null 
                                                || request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024);
```

That's basically I added a null check. So, at the moment, I'm not clear what's going on here!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work around this with a rule like

```
    match /users/{uid}/{document=**} {
      allow read, create, update: if
          request.auth != null &&
          request.auth.uid == uid &&
          (!("resource" in request) || request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid);
    }
```

In this case I wanted to ensure that the "uid" property in the update matches the user's uid.  However, if in the simulator you don't do "Build Document" first then `request.resource` is undefined (I think this is a bug; it should be defined but `null` IMO).

I believe this really only applies in the simulator, and is not a realistic scenario since create/update requests will always contain a document, even an empty one.  But I think I'll keep it in my rule just in case.

Comment: This worked for me! The !("resource" in request) syntax cleared things up for me