# Firebase storage rules size and storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security, rules

I want stoarage rules that apply to all reads and writes:

```
1) Valid if user is authorized
2) Valid if the file is less than 5 mb
```

So i have the following rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth!=null && request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    }
  }
}
```

But im getting an error on the frontend saying firebase storage is rejecting my requests. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is resource a [bytes object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Bytes)? If yes, you want to write `request.resource.size() < 5 * 1024 * 1024`. However, I think that [resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) is a document and doesn't have the size property and you must access the field containing the bytes object to validate the size. You can debug with the `debug` function to know what fields to check.

Comment: please check this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262801/18265638)

Comment: It seems you have a typo in your question: Valid if the file is >5 mb VS request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024. Is it > or < ?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec edited to clarify

Comment: Have you gone through this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262801/18265638)